# Which Sri Vaishnava Acharya drew this world map based on the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, history, sri-vaishnava, ramanujacharya, geography

This picture, showing a world map based on the Mahabharata, is often circulated on the Internet:

[image]

It’s based on [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06005.htm) and subsequent chapters of the Bhishma Parva of the Mahabharata.  But my question is not about the accuracy of this map or it’s relation to the Mahabharata, but rather who drew it.

Most websites I could find say that the famous Sri Vaishnava Acharya Ramanujacharya drew it, e.g. [this website](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/first-ever-world-map-was-sketched-out-based-on-this-mahabharat-verse):

> The first ever world map was sketched thousands of years ago by Indian saint Ramanujacharya, who simply translated the following verse from Mahabharat and gave the world its real face.

But [this website](https://swarajyamag.com/ideas/rabbits-world-maps-and-mahabharata-seeking-the-truth-through-tradition-and-science) says the later Sri Vaishnava Acharya Thiruvenkata Narayana Jeeyar drew:

> The map in question was not drawn by Sri Ramanuja (1017-1137). It was actually drawn by Sriman Thiruvenkata Ramanuja Jeeyar (1806-1877).

So my question is, who really drew it.  Note that I don’t want answers that discuss the nature of the map, or answers speculating about who might have drawn it.  I want definitive proof of who actually drew it.

Comment: current jeeyar  of famous mutt

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Chinna Jeeyar Swami drew a different picture, not this one: http://chinnajeeyar.cpanel.avyayawebservices.com/speeches/did-you-ever-find-the-rabbit-in-the-world-map/

Comment: The picture is not drawn. Koora Narayana Jeeyar used Vayu Puranam to draw the map of the world the way it would look with South at the top. This was done in the 14th Century.

Comment: @M_Raghavan Can you provide more details and this things about Kuranarayana Jeeyar and the Vayu Purana thing?  And where did you get this info?

Comment: @Keshav I learned about the Jeeyar when looking at the original in a museum in Melkote. About the Jeeyar himself: https://guruparamparai.wordpress.com/2013/12/30/kura-narayana-jiyar/